# How to fix redirect OGNL error, Unable to set param?

Tags: struts2, ognl

I am not sure if this is me or if this is a bug.

I got the following error

```
11:52:01,623 ERROR ObjectFactory:27 - Unable to set parameter [dest] in result of type [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult]
Caught OgnlException while setting property 'dest' on type 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult'. - Class: ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor
File: ObjectPropertyAccessor.java
Method: setProperty
Line: 132 - ognl/ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:132:-1
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.internalSetProperty(OgnlUtil.java:392)
```

And my config is pretty minimal

```
<package name="esupport" namespace="/esupport" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="old-esupport" class="com.my.MyRedirectAction">
            <result type="redirect">
            <param name="location">http://some.server.com/init.asp</param>
            <param name="dest">${dest}</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

And my class has a pair of get/set method. And that's it. Nothing Fancy

I have found [this](http://markmail.org/message/qij4ys4xfzklo7u3#query:Caught%20OgnlException%20while%20setting%20property%20on%20type%20%27org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult%27+page:1+mid:c3vpmj7x3ydyzbx2+state:results) thread in the forum. But it doesn't solve my problem

I am using

Struts 2.1.16
Spring 2
Spring Security + CAS

(The funny behavior is it sends me to the CAS server after the error, but I guess it will be corrected after the redirect issue got fixed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems like a bug with Struts2.  they recommend...hiding the error by:

```
<category name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory">
   <priority value="fatal"/>
</category>
```

from....[TroubleShooting guide section on redirects](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue after deploying the application in WAS 7 server. It was an existing application and there was no code change.

Found the following exceptions in the server start-up logs

```
Failed to write out object: ext___405722372
com.ibm.wkplc.extensionregistry.util.XmlUtilException: Unable to write to the given file
```

Just cleared the server cache and restarted it and the issue got resolved.