# WARNING: Caught OgnlException while setting property on type 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult'

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, ognl, actionresult

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848828/how-to-fix-redirect-ognl-error-unable-to-set-param) to solve this warning but even if I put this piece of code I got from link  in package,action and struts tag it says invalid tag.

```
<category name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory">
   <priority value="fatal"/>
</category>
```

**Exception:**

```
Dec 28, 2013 11:10:36 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil internalSetProperty
WARNING: Caught OgnlException while setting property 'reportType' on type 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult'.
ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult.reportType
```

**XML:**

```
   <action name="gatherReportInfo" class="leo.struts.Redirect_Action">   
      <result name="showReportResult" type="redirect">
         <param name="location">/generateReport.jsp</param>
         <param name="reportType">pie</param>   
      </result>
   </action>
```

**Action:**

```
public String getReportType() {
        return reportType;
    }

    public void setReportType(String reportType) {
        this.reportType = reportType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result type `"redirect"` is defined in the class

[`org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/result/ServletRedirectResult.html)

> Calls the `sendRedirect` method to the location specified. The response
>   is told to redirect the browser to the specified location (a new
>   request from the client). The consequence of doing this means that the
>   action (action instance, action errors, field errors, etc.) that was
>   just executed is lost and no longer available. This is because actions
>   are built on a single-thread model. The only way to pass data is
>   through the session or with web parameters (`url?name=value`) which can
>   be OGNL expressions.

Unless you didn't override it by defining a custom result type with the same name.

Unlike the `bean` configuration result types could be overridden. But, it's not, and looking at the class [docs](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/result/ServletRedirectResult.html) you can determine that it doesn't have a field named `reportType`. As a result you got that warning.

If you remove this `param` from the result configuration it'll solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply then how to override ? like  extend org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletRedirectResult with my class and redefine that class with reportType attribute and in xml redefine redirect result with my new class.Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but attribute should be a bean property, so OGNL is able to set its value.